# pycharm error while importing, even though it works in the terminal

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn, pycharm, tensorflow

I have installed the packages TensorFlow and scikit_learn and all its dependencies. When I try importing them using python 2.7.6 or 2.7.10 (I have tried both) in the terminal, it works fine. However, when I do it using pycharm it gives an error.

In the case of **scikit_learn** with the **launcher 2.7.6** says:

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_check_build)

In the case of **scikit_learn** with the **launcher 2.7.10** says:

> ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

In the case of **TensorFlow** with the **launcher 2.7.6** says:

> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>           /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

In the case of **TensorFlow** with the **launcher 2.7.10** says:

> ImportError: No module named copyreg
>
> Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
>       you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
>       please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
>       from there.

I have tried to search in the net but the solutions did not work for me. I have tried to uninstall them and install them again with pip, conda and directly the source code and it gives always the same errors. I have even tried reinstalling pycharm with no better luck.

Other libraries, such as scilab or numpy, work fine in pycharm.

Any ideas? It is just driving me mental. By the way, I am using a Mac OS 10.10.5.

Comment: PyCharm can use a different Python than what you are using on the console. Check your project settings and compare it to which python (use the command "which python" to find out) you are using on the console.

Comment: I have only these two versions of python currently installed, and I have tried to use them both in pycharm and in the terminal. When using the terminal with the 2.7.6 and the 2.7.10 versions, it works fine but it does not in pycharm. I have also tried to run a full python script and it runs fine in the terminal or using idle but it fails with pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I ended up creating a virtual environment, reinstalling everything in there, and calling it through pycharm. I am not entirely sure what was the problem between conda and pycharm, I probably messed up somewhere.

I am now using a different virtual environment depending on the project and I am happier than ever :).

Comment: Did you install a separate pycharm in each environment? or you set the environment params in pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

you should start PyCharm from terminal

`cd /usr/lib/pycharm-community/bin 
./pycharm.sh`

Comment: I remember trying this, but it did not work for me. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib' to Python environment variable. Run-> Edit Configurations -> Environment variables. Hope it works.

Comment: I already solved the issue. So, I cannot test it, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My code was was not working on PyCharm professional. I had PyCharm CE previously installed and it worked from there. I had configured PyCharm CE a while ago and I had forgotten what setup I used but if issues persist, make sure that the packages are installed under Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

hey if there are people still with this problem I would like to tell you the solution. It works for me everytime.

1.Open Pycharm

2.Open PyCharmProject or the folder you are using

3.Click File and there Settings

4.Click Project: PyCharmProjects , there project interpreter

5.Select the global virtual enviroment for this ( including photo thats showing what i did )

6.Check if there are all packages you have installed

[image: This is the picture]