# PyCharm Import Error: Claims 'matplotlib' is not a package, but works successfully in IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

Happy October everyone,

I've successfully downloaded modules before using either the pycharm installer or pip through the command screen, but for some reason when installing matplotlib pycharm cannot recognize it. I've uninstalled and reinstalled, I've installed through both methods, I've followed past similar questions asked on this site which make sure that you have the same interpreter and that it was installed in the right folder ([pycharm error while importing, even though it works in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964994/pycharm-error-while-importing-even-though-it-works-in-the-terminal)).

So, here's the whole problem. Here's is the simple code, submitted into both pycharm and IDLE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,1,3])
plt.show()
```

When submitted into IDLE, my plot appears. When submitted into pycharm, the following error appears:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonProject/matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\PythonProject\matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

I am currently running Python 3.4, PyCharm 2016.2.3, and my matplotlib folders are indeed in my site-packages folder inside my Python34 folder. Also for further verification:

[PyCharm installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BePO4.png)

Please help I've become frustrated since this is the only module I've run into trouble with. I've scoured StackOverflow and related websites to help, I've made sure I have all the requirements, etc.

Comment: Which OS are you using for this ?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 10):

I guess if you named your current writing python module as `matplotlib.py`.That cause the python load your current writing module instead of the actual `matplotlib.py`, which triggers an error.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing. I tried everything except looking at the filename

Comment: You saved my day Thank you. Even I was doing this blunder, i.e naming my workspace as matplotlib. But I guess Pycharm should be smart enough to use its own .py files rather than referring user created files.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). Is not strictly necessary but is good for dividing your project environments.

This is how I tested matplotlib on my Windows 10 installation, hope it helps.

Be sure that you have the python 3 installation folder listed in your Windows `PATH` environment variable, should be already listed if you checked **"Add Python 3.5 to PATH"**:

[image]

You need also to set the Scripts folder in your `PATH` environment variable usually should be this path:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts
```

If you don't do that you have to prepend `python -m` to every command below like this: `python -m <command>`, so the command below would be `python -m pip install virtualenv`. I prefer the first solution.

To test `matplotlib` on Pycharm I've used virtualenv, here is how; first install virtualenv:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then you create your virtual environment in a folder of your choice, in my case I used `python_3_env_00`:

```
virtualenv python_3_env_00
```

After that you can activate you python 3 virtual environment:

```
python_3_env_00/Scripts/activate.bat
```

Now you should see in your command line the active virtual environment `(python_3_venv_00)`, like this:

[image]

Now you can install `matplotlib`:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Fire up PyCharm and add your virtual environment as you project interpreter, go to `File->Settings` search for `Project Interpreter` click on the gear icon and `Add Local` and set the path of your virtual environment, should look like something like this:

[image]

Test it:

[image: test]

Comment: Awesome this looks like it should help! . Can you clarify how I create and activate the virtual environment? The command line keeps telling me the commands are not recognized.

Comment: I've updated the answer, usually you have to set also your Scripts folder to your windows `PATH` environment variable, if you don't you have to prepend  `python -m` to every command, like this: `python -m virtualenv`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

run this code in where the import worked, and run it in the Pycharm project. Compare the lists. Find out which path that is not present in Pycharm sys.path.

Before importing pyplot, append the missing path to sys.path.

```
import sys

sys.path.append("the path")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Does this work?

Comment: Wait, so is linux important for installing matplotlib? Also, when I type in your command it tells me 'sudo' is not a recognized account.

Comment: No linux is not important for matplotlib. Follow the instructions on http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/users/installing.html

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I feel like you didn't read my post. I have matplotlib successfully installed and it works successfully in IDLE, but its not working in my pycharm IDE.

Comment: Yes I did! Can you confirm that:
... open up pycharm in i project which you wish to us matplotlib.

Goto File->Settings->Project:[[ your project name ]]->Project Interpeter.

Here check that: the project interpeter is python3, in usr/bin/python3.. Proceed to check if matplotlib is installed(check the list which appers to you in settings page), else install it(again).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to doubt you! Here is visual proof: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BePO4.png Thanks!

Comment: Didn't mean it like that, I think matplot is important, and if it don't work it's a problem.  I only interested to know why. Does "C:/PythonProject/matplotlib.py" exist? 

My own Pycharm import errors, or diffrences between pycharms "internal interpetator" and comand line is always resolved with checking what sources is used.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps if you are still getting an error:
If you are using PyCharm, it automatically create virtualenv.
Ensure Scripts path is set into ***PATH***

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
```

Then open PyCharm and go to File-> settings. Search for Project Interpreter. You will see window like this 
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSOSa.png)

Click on setting icon -> Existing Environment -> click on **...** give below path

```
C:\Users\Krunal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
```

Click on Apply -> ok and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

After installing matplotlib When I was trying to use matplotlib.pyplot it was giving error   module not found.

I browsed some white papers and found out that we also need to install scipy library to use the matplotlib  so I used the below in my command prompt

python -mpip install scipy

Restarted my kernel session.

It worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing issue while importing matplotlib but it got resolved and now I am  able to use it from pycharm as well.

1. Please make sure you should have visual c++ 14 installed in your system.
   2.If you have more than two python version installed on your system then please install matplotlib from both the version.
   Eg. pip install matplotlib
   pip3 install matplotlib
2. If matplotlib is working from python idle then please check whether you are using correct interpreter in pycharm or not and try to choose pythonw.exe path from your installed location.

Hope this will help, Please do let me know if you are still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but I solved it very easily on pycharm 2019.3.2. In case anyone looking for an easier solution:

I just opened the terminal window on pycharm and typed `pip install matplotlib` and it was all good to go. Every project has its own virtual environment. Opening terminal window of IDE `cd`s to project directory by default. So the installing command was enough.