# ImportError: No module named 'nltk.tokenize'; 'nltk' is not a package

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk

I am using python 3.5.2 within the pycharm IDE in windows 7, and I am having trouble importing the nltk package.

```
import nltk
```

gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python\nltk practice.py", line 7, in <module> from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'nltk.tokenize'; 'nltk' is not a package
```

nltk seems to be properly installed. When i run the following in the terminal

```
pip install nltk
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nltk in c:\users\leee\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages
```

When I run `PATH` in the terminal, or `sys.path` in the python console,

`C:\Users\leee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages` shows up within the long list. That is where all my other packages are installed, and other packages which are all importing properly.

I'm pretty confused right now, and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I would also recommend to use `virtualenv` with PyCharm to isolate your project environments. I had an answer about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937468/pycharm-import-error-claims-matplotlib-is-not-a-package-but-works-successful/39966670#39966670

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This usually happens because you have another file called `nltk.py`. Check your directory (`C:\Python`, where you are running this script) and remove or rename it if it's there. (I suppose the stray `nltk.py` might be somewhere else on your `PYTHONPATH` too.)

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. I had a python file named nltk.py where I was practicing using nltk.

Answer (score 8):

With conda 4.5.4 MosesTokenizer has been moved out of NLTK due to licensing issues #306
https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/306

now what you have to do is

```
pip install mosestokenizer
```

and replace

```
from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesTokenizer, MosesDetokenizer
```

with

```
from mosestokenizer import MosesTokenizer, MosesDetokenizer
```

if you are using conda please note that moses is removed form there and now available at on PyPI

Comment: Are the functions in `mosestokenizer` equivalent to `sacremoses` [here](https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses) which is the package discussed in the `nltk` issues on github.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks. It solved my problem.

Problem:
I created a file "nltk.py" and writing code in that file and try to execute it is giving the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.tokenize'; 'nltk' is not a package'.

Solution:
After that I renamed "nltk.py" to some other then my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm, press on `ctrl`/`cmd` + `shift` + `A`, then type "Python Interpreter"

and make sure you have the same interpreter as the one your `pip` refers to (and not some Jetbrains default one)

**Note:** If you have both `python 2.7` and `python 3.x` installed, the convention is that `pip` refers to the `2.x` dist, and `pip3` refers to `3.x`

Comment: If a version mismatch was the problem, the error would be `ImportError: No module named 'nltk'`.

Comment: This was not my particular problem, but I did not know that distinction could be made. Thank you