# Python ImportError No module named PIL

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

When I try to import pillow

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
```

It comes back with an error message

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I searched for solutions and have tried as much as I could:

a. uninstall and reinstall pip (already in anaconda)

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip uninstall PIL
pip install Pillow
```

```
pip show pillow
Name: Pillow
Version: 7.1.2
Summary: Python Imaging Library (Fork)
Home-page: https://python-pillow.org
Author: Alex Clark (PIL Fork Author)
Author-email: aclark@python-pillow.org
License: HPND
Location: /Users/Jerry/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: scikit-image, imageio, image, bokeh
```

b. install image (it was not installed). didnt help. BTW when I try to import Image only, it still comes out with the same error:

```
ImportError: No module named Image
```

c. conda install, doesnt help.

```
$ conda install -c anaconda pillow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed
```

d. change PIL to either pillow, Pillow, pil, etc. didnt work.

e. reinstall python idle either 3.8 or 3.7. didnt work(maybe totally not relative but as the file is in python3.7 folder, and I have 3.8 installed on my mac, so tried to reinstall 3.7 again, but seems didnt work)

```
Location: /Users/Jerry/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

So I am stuck here and cannot run the code. Does anyone know what is going on and how to solve the problem?
(OS version is Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3)

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: are you in the same virtual environment(conda env) where the pil is installed.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of pip (pip and pip3)? If so, did you try pip3 install pillow

Comment: yes indeed I found 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 in versions folder here, I tried pip3 but didnt work. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I figure out the issue!! Yes it is because of the multiple version of python..

Comment: Using `pip install` can cause problem when you have multiple versions installed, since you don't know which one will be used. You can control this by using `python -m pip`. For example `/usr/bin/python3.7 -m pip install Pillow` https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm Import Error: Claims 'matplotlib' is not a package, but works successfully in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937468/pycharm-import-error-claims-matplotlib-is-not-a-package-but-works-successful)